# Who owns a subframe's name in javascript, the parent or the child?

Tags: javascript, frame, rename

When using web page subframes, the creator (the parent) typically give each subframe a 'name' and can then reference the frames with syntax like   mainWindow.dataFrame. I've run into a browser specific problem which I've tracked down to the fact that a subframe loaded from an external site renames its window to something different than the parent used.  This causes a problem with Google Chrome but not with Firefox.

Firefox appears to keep separate the parent's name and the child's name for the same subframe. This lets the parent javascript continue to work as expected while the child javascript can use its own name as it wants.

Chrome seems to have a different idea and has only a single name for a subframe.  Once the child renames the frame, the parent can no longer access it by name.  Even after different content is loaded into the subframe, the "corruption" persists.

I haven't yet investigated what other browsers do.

I'm aware that there are cross-domain security issues involved in this description. Once the off-site child loads in, we can't access the contents of the subframe.  But having the child rename the window from the parent's side seems like a potential security issue as well.

To solve this I've had to stop using the mainWindow.dataFrame syntax and now use the frames[] array with a fixed index when loading new data into the subframe - ugly but workable.  I guess I'm looking for confirmation that there is no better way around this.  And it would be nice to know who is "right", Firefox or Google.  I'm voting for Firefox.

Comment: Can you post an example that illustrates the issue on http://jsfiddle.net/?

Comment: I think you're talking about two different things, the iframe name (belongs to the parent) and the window title.

Comment: I'll try to put up an example when I get more time.

Comment: Christophe-  This has nothing to do with the "title" property of the frame.  Only the name is in question.  Normally created with <frame name="dataFrame">.  Accessible from javascript using frames[1].name.  My problem occurs when the parent-creator and child-content have different ideas of what the name of the frame should be.  Should the content page of a subframe be allowed to change the 'name' property which was assigned by the parent?

Answer (score 0):

Please forget my initial analysis of my problem.  When I tried to simplify the complicated code I was fixing, I realized more of what was happening.  The problem seems to be unexpected behavior in Firefox.  The frame only has a single name for both Parent and Child.  You get the same response when either context asks for the .name property of the
frame.

The oddity has to do with the automatically created variables/properties that javascript maintains.  If a <frame> is created with a name="subName" attribute, then self.subName gives you a reference to that frame.  If parent or child changes the name of the frame, as with self.subName.name=newName, then a new automatic variable/property self.newName pops into existence and refers to the original frame.  Under Chrome, the old variable/property disappears.  Under Firefox, the old name doesn't go away(!!!) and both properties of the top level window continue to exist and both refer to the same subframe.  This all explains why my original code worked for Firefox but failed on Chrome.